# how to write own logic without using qnamaker

Tags: bots, botframework, sharepoint-online, azure-language-understanding

I am still trying to understand Chatbots. Currently i have already made chatbot which is integrated in skype. I have `Sharepoint online` where user search for FAQ. If they dont find then they ask `BOT` which sends request to `LUIS` and `Qnamaker`. 
Qnamaker then sends response back by looking it into its database. I upload FAQ from sharepoint to Qnamaker using sharepoint workflows. But i want to write my own logic and get rid of Qnamaker.

What are ways to do it? Any good tutorials? I also wanted to know how the flow happens. For example if we dont use Qnamaker then we fire queries in sharepoint based on what user asked? I dont understand how i can fire queries in sharepoint if user makes typo then we will not get anything from sharepoint. So any tips on how to implement this without using qnamaker is highly appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

The FAQ bot generator is a subset of the main Microsoft bot framework. You should do some research on [the Microsoft Bot Framework](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/). The link above takes you right to the documentation overview of the bot framework and from there you can get into developing one. They have links to a few sample projects as well as a large number of code snippets within some of the article explanations. It has a full setup guide that will walk you through the initial setup so it should be easy to get a basic echo bot running, but if you are not a programmer you should stick to the FAQ generator.

I suggest you use either node.js or c# to develop the bot since these are directly supported by the framework. I am personally using c# to build my bot from the ground up. The purpose of mine is to be used within a customer facing android/ios app that will help with questions, checking the status of different things, and even paying bills.

Just remember you will need to manually set up your cloud hosting. I host mine in azure alongside a web interface I built for it (you can build the website inside your bot if you are using c#, just replace the default.htm file in the web.config with the main page of the interface).

Comment: I just wanted to know how can i write my own logic to do search in my sharepoint database.. As you can see in question that i am using qnamaker to do search for FAQ. I need good links for it